# C function unexpectedly alters value

Tags: c, ncurses

I've got a strange problem that google and SO search can't help with. It's possibly something really simple but i've been thrashing about for a couple of hours and can't nut it out.

I'm doing up tetris in C using Ncurses (using Ubuntu).

My main function calls an updatePiece() function, passes in both a pointer to a struct that tracks the state of the active piece, as well as the keyboard input buffer.

The struct:

```
struct piece {                                                                  
    struct coords pos;                                                          
    char currentMap[4][MAPSIZEX][MAPSIZEY];                                     
    int type;                                                                   
    int rotation;                                                               
    int leftColumn;                                                             
    int rightColumn;                                                            
    int bottomRow;                                                              
};
```

The updatePiece Function:

```
void updatePiece(struct piece* piece, int input) {                              
    switch(input) {                                                             
        case KEY_UP:                                                            
            ++piece->rotation;                                                  
            if(piece->rotation == 4)                                            
                piece->rotation = 0;                                            
            getBoundary(piece);                                                 
            break;                                                              
        case KEY_RIGHT:                                                         
            if(piece->pos.x + piece->rightColumn != WELLSIZEX)                  
                ++piece->pos.x;                                                 
            break;                                                              
        case KEY_LEFT:                                                          
            if(piece->pos.x + piece->leftColumn != 0)                           
                --piece->pos.x;                                                 
            break;                                                              
        case 'p':                                                               
            ++piece->type;                                                      
            selectMap(piece);                                                   
            getBoundary(piece);                                                 
            break;                                                              
    }                                                                           

    if(piece->pos.y + piece->bottomRow >= WELLSIZEY)                            
        piece->pos.y = 0;                                                       
    ++piece->pos.y;                                                             
}
```

Cool, so the function moves the piece around, rotates etc. I'll eventually use rand() to select a new piece once the current piece becomes 'dead' etc., but for now i'm detecting 'p' being input and using that to increment the counter at will.

However, the piece will seemingly only rotate once. Using mvprintw() tells me the content of piece->type appears to not change.

So I jumped into gdb to find out what is going on. Everything goes swimmingly at first; 'p' is detected at stdin, piece->type is indeed incremented, then the selectMap() function is called. Here is where something funny happens.

```
void selectMap(struct piece* piece) {                                           
    switch(piece->type) {                                                       
        // T Piece                                                              
        case 0:                                                                 
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][0], "....");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][1], ".X..");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][2], "XXX.");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][3], "....");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][0], "....");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][1], ".X..");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][2], ".XX.");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][3], ".X..");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][0], "....");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][1], "....");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][2], "XXX.");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][3], ".X..");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][0], "....");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][1], ".X..");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][2], "XX..");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][3], ".X..");                            
            return;                                                             
        // J Piece                                                               
        case 1:                                                                 
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][0], "....");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][1], ".X..");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][2], ".X..");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][3], "XX..");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][0], "....");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][1], "X...");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][2], "XXX.");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][3], "....");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][0], "....");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][1], ".XX.");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][2], ".X..");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][3], ".X..");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][0], "....");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][1], "....");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][2], "XXX.");                            
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][3], "..X.");                            
            return;   

           <REST OF FUNCTION OMITTED>
    }
}
```

The function changes the currentPiece char arrays to match the current piece type. Everything copies just fine, but as soon as the function exits piece->type is set to 0.

I have no idea why. Piece is passed by reference, so it shouldn't be a scope issue. Using a switch or a bunch of if/elses has no effect. Using break or return has no effect.

It's probably something really simple and dumb, but as a self-taught coder it has me stumped.

Any help appreciated. Entire code follows (feel free to critique!):

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WELLSIZEX 10
#define WELLSIZEY 20
#define MAPSIZEX  4
#define MAPSIZEY  4
#define DELAY     100000

struct coords {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct piece {
    struct coords pos;
    char currentMap[4][MAPSIZEX][MAPSIZEY];
    int type;
    int rotation;
    int leftColumn;
    int rightColumn;
    int bottomRow;
};


void selectMap(struct piece* piece) {
    switch(piece->type) {
        // T Piece
        case 0:
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][1], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][2], "XXX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][3], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][1], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][2], ".XX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][3], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][1], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][2], "XXX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][3], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][1], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][2], "XX..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][3], ".X..");
            return;
        // J Piece
        case 1:
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][1], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][2], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][3], "XX..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][1], "X...");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][2], "XXX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][3], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][1], ".XX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][2], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][3], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][1], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][2], "XXX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][3], "..X.");
            return;
        // L Piece
        case 2:
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][1], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][2], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][3], ".XX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][1], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][2], "XXX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][3], "X...");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][1], "XX..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][2], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][3], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][1], "..X.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][2], "XXX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][3], "....");
            return;
        // O Piece  
        case 3:
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][1], ".XX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][2], ".XX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][3], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][1], ".XX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][2], ".XX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][3], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][1], ".XX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][2], ".XX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][3], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][1], ".XX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][2], ".XX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][3], "....");
            return;
        // I Piece
        case 4:
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][0], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][1], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][2], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][3], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][1], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][2], "XXXX");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][3], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][0], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][1], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][2], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][3], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][1], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][2], "XXXX");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][3], "....");
            return;
        // S Piece
        case 5:
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][1], ".XX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][2], "XX..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][3], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][1], "X...");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][2], "XX..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][3], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][1], ".XX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][2], "XX..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][3], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][1], "X...");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][2], "XX..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][3], ".X..");
            return;
        // Z Piece
        case 6:
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][1], "XX..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][2], ".XX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][3], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][1], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][2], "XX..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][3], "X...");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][1], "XX..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][2], ".XX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][3], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][1], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][2], "XX..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][3], "X...");
            return;
        }
/*
        if(piece->type == 0) {
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][1], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][2], "XXX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][3], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][1], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][2], ".XX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][3], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][1], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][2], "XXX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][3], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][1], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][2], "XX..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][3], ".X..");
        }
        if(piece->type == 1) {
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][1], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][2], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][3], "XX..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][1], "X...");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][2], "XXX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[1][3], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][1], ".XX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][2], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[2][3], ".X..");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][0], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][1], "....");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][2], "XXX.");
            strcpy(piece->currentMap[3][3], "..X.");
        }
*/

}

void inits(struct piece* piece, char wellMap[WELLSIZEX][WELLSIZEY]) {
    piece->pos.x = piece->pos.y = 1;
    piece->rotation = 0;
    piece->type = 0;
    piece->leftColumn = 0;
    piece->rightColumn = 2;
    piece->bottomRow = 2;

    selectMap(piece);

    int x, y;
    for(y = 0; y < WELLSIZEY; ++y)
        for(x = 0; x < WELLSIZEX; ++x)
            wellMap[x][y] = '.';
}

void getBoundary(struct piece* piece) {
    // T Piece 
    if(piece->type == 0) {
        if(piece->rotation == 0) {
            piece->leftColumn = 0;
            piece->rightColumn = 2;
            piece->bottomRow = 2;
            return;
        }
        if(piece->rotation == 1) {
            piece->leftColumn = 1;
            piece->rightColumn = 2;
            piece->bottomRow = 3;
            return;
        }
        if(piece->rotation == 2) {
            piece->leftColumn = 0;
            piece->rightColumn = 2;
            piece->bottomRow = 3;
            return;
        }
        if(piece->rotation == 3) {
            piece->leftColumn = 0;
            piece->rightColumn = 1;
            piece->bottomRow = 3;
            return;
        }
    }
    // J Piece
    if(piece->type == 1) {
        if(piece->rotation == 0) {
            piece->leftColumn = 0;
            piece->rightColumn = 1;
            piece->bottomRow = 3;
            return;
        }
        if(piece->rotation == 1) {
            piece->leftColumn = 0;
            piece->rightColumn = 2;
            piece->bottomRow = 2;
            return;
        }
        if(piece->rotation == 2) {
            piece->leftColumn = 1;
            piece->rightColumn = 2;
            piece->bottomRow = 3;
            return;
        }
        if(piece->rotation == 3) {
            piece->leftColumn = 0;
            piece->rightColumn = 2;
            piece->bottomRow = 3;
            return;
        }
    }
    // L Piece
    if(piece->type == 2) { 
        if(piece->rotation == 0) {
            piece->leftColumn = 1;
            piece->rightColumn = 2;
            piece->bottomRow = 3;
            return;
        }
        if(piece->rotation == 1) {
            piece->leftColumn = 0;
            piece->rightColumn = 2;
            piece->bottomRow = 3;
            return;
        }
        if(piece->rotation == 2) {
            piece->leftColumn = 0;
            piece->rightColumn = 1;
            piece->bottomRow = 3;
            return;
        }
        if(piece->rotation == 3) {
            piece->leftColumn = 0;
            piece->rightColumn = 2;
            piece->bottomRow = 2;
            return;
        }
    }
    // O Piece
    if(piece->type == 3) {
        piece->leftColumn = 1;
        piece->rightColumn = 2;
        piece->bottomRow = 2;
        return;
    }
    // I Piece
    if(piece->type == 4) {
        if(piece->rotation == 0 || piece->rotation == 2) {
            piece->leftColumn = 1;
            piece->rightColumn = 1;
            piece->bottomRow = 3;
            return;
        }
        if(piece->rotation == 1 || piece->rotation == 3) {
            piece->leftColumn = 0;
            piece->rightColumn = 3;
            piece->bottomRow = 2;
            return;
        }
    }
    // S/Z Piece
    if(piece->type == 5 || piece->type == 6) {
        if(piece->rotation == 0 || piece->rotation == 2) {
            piece->leftColumn = 0;
            piece->rightColumn = 2;
            piece->bottomRow = 2;
            return;
        }
        if(piece->rotation == 1 || piece->rotation == 3) {
            piece->leftColumn = 0;
            piece->rightColumn = 1;
            piece->bottomRow = 3;
            return;
        }
    }
}

void updatePiece(struct piece* piece, int input) {
    switch(input) {
        case KEY_UP:
            ++piece->rotation;
            if(piece->rotation == 4)
                piece->rotation = 0;
            getBoundary(piece);
            break;
        case KEY_RIGHT:
            if(piece->pos.x + piece->rightColumn != WELLSIZEX)
                ++piece->pos.x;
            break;
        case KEY_LEFT:
            if(piece->pos.x + piece->leftColumn != 0)
                --piece->pos.x;
            break;
        case 'p':
            ++piece->type;
            selectMap(piece);
            getBoundary(piece);
            break;
    }

    if(piece->pos.y + piece->bottomRow >= WELLSIZEY)
        piece->pos.y = 0;
    ++piece->pos.y;
}

void drawWell(char wellMap[WELLSIZEX][WELLSIZEY]) {
    int y, x;
    for(y = 0; y < WELLSIZEY; ++y)
        for(x = 0; x < WELLSIZEX; ++x)
            mvaddch(y, x, wellMap[x][y]);

    for(y = 0; y < WELLSIZEY; ++y) {
        mvaddch(y,         0, '|');
        mvaddch(y, WELLSIZEX, '|');
    }

    for(x = 0; x <= WELLSIZEX; ++x) {
        mvaddch(        0, x, '-');
        mvaddch(WELLSIZEY, x, '-');
    }
}

void drawPiece(struct piece piece) {
    int x, y;
    for(y = 0; y < MAPSIZEY; ++y)
        for(x = 0; x < MAPSIZEX; ++x)
            mvaddch(piece.pos.y + y, piece.pos.x + x, piece.currentMap[piece.rotation][y][x]);
}

int main(void) {
    struct piece piece;
    char wellMap[WELLSIZEX][WELLSIZEY];

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    curs_set(FALSE);
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    inits(&piece, wellMap);
    while(1) {
        clear();
        /*
        if(isCollision) {
            blit();
            getNewPiece();
            piece.pos.y = 0;
            piece.pos.x = 3;
        }
        */
        updatePiece(&piece, getch());
        drawWell(wellMap);
        drawPiece(piece);
        mvprintw(2, 12, "l %d / dn %d / r %d / pce %d / rot %d",
                 piece.leftColumn, piece.bottomRow, piece.rightColumn,
                 piece.type, piece.rotation);
        refresh();
        usleep(DELAY);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using

```
char currentMap[4][MAPSIZEX][MAPSIZEY];
```

field.

At the same time you're doing

```
strcpy(piece->currentMap[0][0], "....");
```

and stuff like that.

The strcpy() actually writes 5 (not 4) bytes, because of the zero-terminator.

Since you have the 'type' field right after the currentMap, you get zero there (the first  byte in 'type' gets overwritten).

Either use memcpy() for piece->currentMap[i][j] or allocate more than 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

`MAPSIZEY` is `4`, but you are copying 5 characters into each of those arrays (copying the string `".X.."` with `strcpy()` copies the four characters you can see plus the null terminator).

It's likely that the last null terminator is overwriting the first byte of the `type` value, and if you have a little-endian machine that will set the least significant byte of `type` to zero.